# How to create dynamic connection string for Crystal Report in Asp.Net C# in my case?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have multiple iis, all the iis webpages are connecting with different database. I have too many Crystal Reports, once I upload it to all multiple iis, it has to connect to that corresponding database.

I don't have any idea to make connection string in crystal report.

Here is my ReportViewer code

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument _rdStudents = new ReportDocument();

        Trace.Write("/CrystalReportFiles/RMS/Inventory/");
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~" + Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString());

        _rdStudents.Load(reportPath);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdStudents;
    }
```

How can i make connection string here. I saw some of this [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1494220.aspx?Dynamically%20setting%20connection%20string%20to%20a%20report). But I didn't get the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this.

```
TableLogOnInfos TableLogOnInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo TableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables Tables;
ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName";
ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Database";
ConnectionInfo.UserID = "UserId";
ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password";

ReportDocument _rdStudents = new ReportDocument();
Trace.Write("/CrystalReportFiles/RMS/Inventory/");
string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~" + Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString());

_rdStudents.Load(reportPath);

Tables = _rdStudents.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in Tables)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        TableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnectionInfo;
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(TableLogOnInfo);
    }
 CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdStudents;
```

Comment: Do I need to add the above code after `_rdStudents.Load(reportPath);` this code?

Comment: Check current code. I have merged with your code. You should add after 
    _rdStudents.Load(reportPath); this code.

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error occured. I directly put the server IP,database name,username of db and password. Is it odbc connection?

Comment: This is not odbc connection. Are you using odbc connection?

Comment: No i am not using odbc. I want to use connection string only.

Comment: This is Connection String. Wait a bit.

Comment: Working now. I am updating my answer including your code. Give me few moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174584/discussion-between-liam-neesan-and-noor-all-safaet).